# how to update an array object in javascript by changing input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash

I want to update an array of object in Javascript and I have added a Fiddle for that.

[Updated FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/MWadX/404/)

Can someone please guide me?

Thanks in Advance

### My Fiddle Code:

```
var category_number = 0;
var my_data = [
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=" + category_number,  // This variable should change from updateData function
    hash_number_1: 1  
  },
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_2: 2
  },
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_3: 3
  },
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_4: 4
  },
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_5: 5
  },
];

var updateData = function() {
  var my_value = document.getElementById('my_value').value;
  if (my_value == 1) {
    category_number = 5;
  } else if (my_value == 2) {
    category_number = 1;
  } else if (my_value == 3) {
    category_number = 7;
  }
  // This category_number should update the my_data Array Object
  console.log(category_number);
  //my_data.push

  // Here is my question. Can I make the category_number to a global variable and change or any other neat way to do it?

}
$(document).on('change', '#my_value', updateData);

/* This function load once and I want the my_data change to applicable to the below function */
(function() {
    //$.each(my_datas, function(i, my_data) {
    //my_data.show_function = function() {
        //if .....
      console.log('final function');
    //}
  //}
})();
```

Here is my question. Can I make the category_number to a global variable and change or any other neat way to do it?

### Expected Result:

Update the url category_number of the first object of my_data.

Ex: if the `input value is 3`, then the `url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=7"`

Comment: _"This category_number should update the my_data Array Object"_ How should array be updated ?

Comment: That's where I have been clueless to update the array hash. I updated the question.

Comment: Your fiddle is missing a quote ln: 15

Comment: Well, with what you are asking, I can give you this: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/6ygnb4r1/2/ - A bit more info on what you mean by `updating the array hash` might be useful, since there is only 1 array with objects.

Comment: How is category_number supposed to influence the array? Can you please provide us what you are expecting as a **result**? it doesn't seem to be the hardest task in the universe, but I'm seriously unable to understand what you need to do. Besides, there is a typo in your fiddle, you're missing a `"`. Here is the fixed one: https://jsfiddle.net/MWadX/402/

Comment: Thanks and I have updated the question and the fiddle.

Comment: would it be a possibility to add a new param to the objects? like 'uri-params'  containing either an empty string if there is no category, or if there is one, the whole part after the "?"?

Comment: @jacksbox like what? can you show an example please?

Comment: @sri see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
  var my_data = [
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
    params: "columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=5",
    hash_number_1: 1  
  },
  {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
    params: "",
    hash_number_2: 2
  }
];
```

if category_number number changes you could iterate over the array and change every field, where

```
var updateData = function() {
...
my_data[0]['params'] = "columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=" + category_number;
...
}
```

If you need the url, you just build it like this

```
my_data[index][url] + my_data[index][params]
```

As I dont know what your app will do, you could also simple update the url for the first array element?

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is possible. But it will only update the first object url? I want other url should be same as it is now.

Comment: is the first object the only object in the array for which the url will change with the category_number or will there be other array fields changing as well?

Comment: Just the first object and I don't want to change any other object. Updating the first object url by the input value change.

Comment: Thanks @jacksbox. I will try this in my app and come back to you.

Comment: I have a function loading when page refreshes. Is it possible that function get the my_data variable after the variable changes and without calling that function again?

Comment: you have to replace the "index" in the code above with the position in the array, in your case 0. Can you explain your second question a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this?

```js
var category_number = 0;
var my_data = [{
  url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=1",
  hash_number_1: 1
}, {
  url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
  hash_number_2: 2
}, {
  url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
  hash_number_3: 3
}, {
  url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
  hash_number_4: 4
}, {
  url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?",
  hash_number_5: 5
}];

$("#my_value").change(function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  var category_number = 0;
  if (val == 1) {
    category_number = 5;
  } else if (val == 2) {
    category_number = 1;
  } else if (val == 3) {
    category_number = 7;
  }

  var url = my_data[0].url;
  url = url.substr(0, url.length - 1) + category_number;
  my_data[0].url = url;

  console.log(my_data);
  console.log(my_data[0]); //first object that has been updated
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="my_value" id="my_value" />
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, can you please grab that copy for the source? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How about this ...

```js
function getMyData(category_number) {
  return [{
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?columns%5Bcategory_id%5D=" + category_number, // This variable should change from updateData function
    hash_number_1: 1
  }, {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_2: 2
  }, {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_3: 3
  }, {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_4: 4
  }, {
    url: "/some/url/some_model_name.js?", // Forget about this and it's never going to change. 
    hash_number_5: 5
  }, ];
}

var updateData = function() {
    var my_value = document.getElementById('my_value').value;
    if (my_value == 1) {
      category_number = 5;
    } else if (my_value == 2) {
      category_number = 1;
    } else if (my_value == 3) {
      category_number = 7;
    }
    // This category_number should update the my_data Array Object
    console.log(category_number);

    console.log(getMyData(category_number))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The function is not ending?

Comment: Could the down voter care to say what's wrong with this approach ?

Comment: Sorry Aukhan, that's not me.